# From SQL to Laravel 8 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created a query in **SQL** and it works quite well.

```
SELECT learning_content_number,
            course,
            count(required) as required,
            count(overdue) as overdue,
            count(status) as status,
            count(completion_date) as completion_date

            FROM hse_leatros
            GROUP BY learning_content_number
```

Now I want to translate it in **Laravel 8 Eloquent**. This script works, but I am missing the information about the course.

```
$courses = Leatro::groupBy('learning_content_number')
        ->selectRaw('count(required) as required, learning_content_number')
        ->selectRaw('count(overdue) as overdue, learning_content_number')
        ->selectRaw('count(status) as status, learning_content_number')
        ->selectRaw('count(completion_date) as completion_date, learning_content_number')
        ->get();
```

How can I enter the in the code that it is transferred with?

My DB-Table structur:

```
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('employee_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('course')->nullable();
        $table->string('required')->nullable();
        $table->string('mandatory')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('due_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('completion_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('overdue')->nullable();
        $table->string('learning_content_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('assigned_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('assigned_mechanism')->nullable();
        $table->string('cost_centre_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('hash')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
```

Comment: Please provide your table structure, test data and required result [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just add `->select('learning_content_number',  'course')`:

```
$courses = $db::table('hse_leatros')
    ->groupBy('learning_content_number',  'course')
    ->select('learning_content_number',  'course')
    ->selectRaw('count(required) as required')
    ->selectRaw('count(overdue) as overdue')
    ->selectRaw('count(status) as status')
    ->selectRaw('count(completion_date) as completion_date')
    ;

echo $courses->toSql();

print_r($courses->get());
```

[Laravel QueryBuilder online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/d6277381d681d1c46d21d6f14693f43a/php/php8/f1cb39a90477bfc47878910c075cba1a/)

Comment: Perhaps `$courses->dd()` would do better, you'd also get the values necessary for the `?`'s